# Spring controller returns a list of values from application configuration file

Tags: java, spring, controller

My problem seems very simple, but I'm blocked on it for 2 hours.
I'm using Java with Spring and I want to save a map of string information (key, value) in the application.yaml file.
Then I want to return it from a controller exposed to a frontend application.

My first solution was to use this structure in the configuration file:

```
bandwidth:
  - configurations:
    - type: a
      path: AAA
    - type: e
      path: TTT
    - type: I
      path: FFF
    - type: o
      path: XXX
```

And to create a constructor like:

```
import ...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bandwidth")
public class BandwidthController {

    @Value("${bandwidth.configurations}")
    private Map<String,String> configurations;

    @GetMapping("/config")
    public Map<String,String> getListOfPath() {
        return this.configurations;
    }
}
```

Does someone can give me a working example of a solution for this case?

Comment: I think you should have not Map, but list of configurations. So you need to create class Configuration with 2 fields type and path. And try to inject values from properties file into List<Configuration>

Comment: I believe you can make a map directly from the cconfigurations by structuring the yaml differently.. Use the value of the type and the value of the path directly instead of specifying `type: ...` and `value: ...`. So under `configurations:` a line could be `a: AAA`. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-inject-map

Comment: Update: I tested this, and it seems like it only works for propery-classes marked with `@ConfigurationProperties`, not directly with `@Value`. Refer to Ganael D's answer for a working case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem not too long ago. What I did was using a second config class and annotating it with a few Spring Boot annotations. You can create the following class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bandwidth")
public class Config {

    private List<Map<String, String>> configurations;

}
```

What it's gonna do is create a class that will look for the `configurations` property of the property you'll have given in the prefix parameter of @ConfigurationProperties in the application.yml file and store it in an attribute. This class needs a getter and a setter for this attribute, which are created here thanks to `@Getter` and `@Setter`.

You could then get the config in your Controller simply by providing it as an autowired `Config` attribute:

```
@Autowired
private Config config;

@GetMapping("/config")
@ResponseBody(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public List<Map<String,String>> getListOfPath() {
        return this.config.getConfigurations();
    }
```

---

*Please note* that if your config properties contain `-`, you're gonna have to store that in a list. While it makes sense to do that with your configuration objects, it seems inappropriate for the property `configurations`. I would change your configuration file to:

```
bandwidth:
    configurations:
        - type: a
          path: AAA
        - type: e
          path: TTT
        - type: I
          path: FFF
        - type: o
          path: XXX
```

If you don't remove the `-` in front of configurations, you're gonna need to tweak my solution to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Ganael D
The solution I did is pretty similar but a bit longer than yours:

- The class where I have "public static void main" method I added "@EnableConfigurationProperties({ApplicationProperties.class})"
- Where "ApplicationProperties" is a new class where I added "@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")"
- In my configuration file, I just added this "application" on the top of my list like:

```
    application:
       stuff:
         disks:
            - name: "aa"
              path: "XXX"
            - name: "bb"
              path: "ZZZ"
```

- and "ApplicationProperties" class matches the content of my application object (here it has an attribute stuff, having a list of {name, path} object in an array named disks

And it is working fine.
Thank you very much for the time you spent helping me :)